# Question with ‘top’ command

Tags: linux, centos

When i run top command, it prints as follows in third line

```
0.1%us 0.2%sy 0.1%sy 0.0%ni 99.5%id 0.1%wa 0.0%hi 0.0%si 0.0%st
```

i want to know what does the line mean ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shows CPU utilization details. “0.1%us” user processes are using 0.1%; “0.2%sy” system processes are using 0.2%; “99.5%id” percentage of available cpu; “0.1%wa” time CPU is waiting for IO.

When first analyzing the Cpu(s) line in top look at the %id to see how much cpu is available. If %id is low then focus on %us, %sy, and %wa to determine what is using the CPU.

Comment: Hi Rajat, I still hava a question with top. I notice that, the id% is 94%, but the total 'CPU%' of user processes is 12% or 13%, why it is not 6% ?

Comment: The process percentages are in terms of 1 CPU, while the numbers on the third line are in terms of all CPUs.